# При использование Asp.net Core Identity не работает авторизация, User.Identity.IsAuthenticated всегда false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity-3

Здравствуйте работаю с Identity недавно, решил сделать кастомное приложение взяв пример с сайта метанит [та самая глава](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/16.4.php)!
Не знаю с чем связанно, но в контексте пользователя банально нету. Смотрел через отладку, ничего не нашел. После авторизации, я в представлении произвожу проверку при помощи свойства User.Identity.IsAuthenticated, но я не понимаю почему, но там всегда false. Самое удивительное, что когда я поставил breakpoint на метод Логина, моя проверка на удачную авторизацию спокойно проходится и свойство Succeeded всегда true, из-за чего я и запутался и не понимаю с чем это может быть связанно. Версия AspNetCore 2.1.201.
Код логина:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var result =
                await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // проверяем, принадлежит ли URL приложению
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.ReturnUrl) && Url.IsLocalUrl(model.ReturnUrl))
                {
                    return Redirect(model.ReturnUrl);
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Неправильный логин и (или) пароль");
            }
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

Код Startup-a:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){ 
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(options =>{
  options.UseMySql(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(opts => {
            opts.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            opts.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            opts.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opts.Password.RequireUppercase = false;               
        })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
```

Код представления в котором производится проверка:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated){
    <p>@User.Identity.Name</p>
    <form method="post" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="LogOff">
    <input type="submit" value="Выход" />
    </form>
}
else{
     <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Login">Вход</a>
     <a asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Register">Регистрация</a>
}
```

Comment: Ну так навскидку: а у вас пользователь хоть один создан? И покажите на скриншоте содержимое вашей модели, когда вы только вошли в метод. Вы например можете взять и создать пустой проект asp.net-core 2.1 и указать individual user account и вам будет уже готовые контроллеры-вью-модели-миграции созданы из коробки. А тут у вас почти тоже самое, только вы переписывали сами и вероятно где-то по дороге ошиблись. В текущем коде всё выглядит правильно, ищите ошибку в другом месте.

Comment: @AK да тут в другом дело, как мне кажется. Action написан так, что вид показывается только при ошибках входа в систему. Ну и откуда в таком случае в свойстве IsAuthenticated возьмется true?

Comment: На днях тоже начал писать проект на Asp.net Core 2.1, хотел отключить на время разработки SSL, да только после отключения - вырубалась напрочь авторизация (не логинило). Сделал вывод, что для авторизации необходим SSL (HTTPS).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ у меня pet проект на core 2.1 с токен аутентификацией без SSL, полет нормальный

Comment: @tym32167 С токен я так понимаю JWT? С ним у меня проблем нет, а вот стандартная Cookie только по SSL у меня лично работает, так и не смог побороть. Тут видел [задавали](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/729243/asp-core-2-аунтификация-без-ssl-по-http) на эту тему вопрос, ответа человек так и не дождался )

Comment: @Half - где вы после валидации данных , введенных пользователем,  сохраняете эти данные ?    
После входа зарегистрированного пользователя - с чем вы его данные сравниваете ? Где проверяете - есть ли такой пользователь в базе данных или нет ? Откройте базу данных в проекте  - есть там ваш пользователь ? если делаете кастомное решение  - по пунктам порядок создания решения плиз представьте ...

Comment: @Eikhner по идее это работа для SignInManager

Comment: @tym32167  - в кастомной реализации  - неизвестно чья это работа

Comment: @Eikhner так она ж тут вроде не кастомная

Comment: @Eikhner реализация метода здесь не кастомная, а взята с библиотеки, данные сохраняются в бд, которую я указал в аppsetting-e, я проверял после регистрации пользователь появляется в бд, еще находил подобный вопрос на иностранном стаковерфлоу [cсылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838912/user-identity-isauthenticated-returns-false-after-signinasync-invoked?noredirect=1&lq=1), только я не понял, как человек решил, но ответ там вроде присутствует, если сможете помочь с переводом и понятным языком объяснить, как решить это, я был бы очень благодарен )

Comment: @AK да вы правы, будет все сразу из коробки, но там столько много файлов, и прочих ненужных вещей, которые я точно использовать не буду, вот я и хотел аккуратно сделать с нуля.

Comment: @tym32167 Сегодня добавлял стандартные страницы identity в проект (ибо по стандарту в 2.1 они все переехали в отдельную dll). Так мне выдало по типу "инструкции" о том, как включить Identity в проекте, так последняя строка гласит "Apps that use ASP.NET Core Identity should also use HTTPS.". Вся инструкция: [тык](https://pastebin.com/MyEqDgkp). Получается, что в 2.1 для Identity SSL обязателен стал...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ `should use` - выглядит как пожелание, а не строгое правило

Comment: Нашел решение, все оказалось куда проще, вообщем каким-то странным образом моя студия думала, что у меня кор 2.1, и самое прикольное что через консольку введя команда dotner --version выскакивало тоже 2.1, никогда не верьте ни тому, ни другому, заходите в корень папки и смотрите версию вашего дотнет-а, я все поставил, а и человек выше был прав, SSL и HTTPS обязательны для Identity. Будьте внимательны и не повторяйте моих ошибок. Вопрос закрыт...

Answer (score 0):

Будьте внимательны с версиями, потому что гайд с метанита рассчитан на версию выше 2.0, что и оказалось решением моей проблемы.